# Novices Guide to Using The Terminal Command?

Tags: discussion

**Suitability Of Question**

I liked to ask a question regarding using the Terminal Command. I have never used the terminal command (so obviously am a bit anxious), but alot of answers here at Ask Different, gives ways of solving the problem(s) with a terminal hack (if that is the correct terminology).

I want to ideally know how to use Terminal or be introduced to it (or am I really being scared for nothing) ?

Answer (score 4):

Simon, this is a great question for the main site. It will be even better if you put to words one or two things that have caused you to be anxious. It doesn't matter if they are good reasons, bad reasons, but will help others searching on google for those exact concerns to find your question and seek help like you have.

Let's work out the details of your question here on meta so that you have a very good experience asking how to learn on the main site.

Comment: Its just I've never used it so don't really know how to start, or if I enter the text incorrectly, how to easily change the correction....If I'm making sense. Or to reverse the terminal hack if necessary.

Comment: Perfect, Let's pick one question on the main site you wonder about or one task you'd like to learn how to do.

Comment: Thats fine, here one http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91722/disable-dashboard-in-mountain-lion

Comment: Perfect - so I'm going to be a bit dumb now. Rather than guess what you want - are you curious how to use the command to make that change or do you want to learn how the answerer knew what to do?

Comment: Primarily how to use the command in order to make the required change.

Comment: Perfect! You have a great case to ask for help in understanding how to accomplish that task. You can say you want to implement this and don't know where to start. We can take it from there. Link to your question here if I miss it or it doesn't get a good answer / runs into issues.

Comment: Still haven't had time this weekend, shall get round to it during the coming week.

Comment: No rush - the site will be here in a week and hopefully in a month too /

Comment: I hope it will be here for many years to come :)